# java cpu usage monitoring

Tags: java, cpu-usage

Is there a way in monitoring CPU usage using pure Java?

Answer (score 10):

There is a gem in the comments on the article which kgiannakakis linked:

[javasysmon](https://github.com/jezhumble/javasysmon/wiki)

> JavaSysMon manages processes and
> reports useful system performance
> metrics cross-platform. You can think
> of it as a cross-platform version of
> the UNIX `top’ command, along with the
> ability to kill processes. It comes in
> the form of a single JAR file /..

-works on Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, and Solaris.

Answer (score 7):

How about using jmx mbeans?

```
final OperatingSystemMXBean myOsBean= 
            ManagementFactory.getOperatingSystemMXBean();
double load = myOsBean.getSystemLoadAverage();
```

Comment: Gives -1 for me on Windows platforms.

Comment: docs says -1 means not supported. But on linux I get value less than what OS says, so I assume it is the CPU load used by current JVM?

Comment: ref doc http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html

Answer (score 6):

You *can* use jMX beans to calculate a CPU load. Note that this measures CPU load of your java program, not the overall system load. (the question didn't specify which)

Initialize:

```
    ThreadMXBean newBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
    try
    {
        if (this.newBean.isThreadCpuTimeSupported())
            this.newBean.setThreadCpuTimeEnabled(true);
        else
            throw new AccessControlException("");
    }
    catch (AccessControlException e)
    {
        System.out.println("CPU Usage monitoring is not available!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

Then as your loop (assuming your application uses a loop, otherwise what's the point in measuring CPU usage?) use this:

```
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long lastThreadTime = newBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();

    while (true)
    {
        // Do something that takes at least 10ms (on windows)
        try
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 20000000; i++)
                j = (j + i) * j / 2;
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }

        // Calculate coarse CPU usage:
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        long threadTime = newBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        double load = (threadTime - lastThreadTime) / (double)(time - lastTime);
        System.out.println((float)load);

        // For next iteration.
        lastTime = time;
        lastThreadTime = threadTime;
    }
```

You need to use double precision because a long doesn't fit in a float (though it might work 99.9999999999999999% of the time)

> If the 'something' you're doing takes less than approximately 1.6ms (Windows), then the returned value will not even have increased at all and you'll perpetually measure 0% CPU erroneously.

Because `getCurrentThreadCpuTime` is VERY inaccurate (with delays less than 100ms), smoothing it helps a lot:

```
    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    long lastThreadTime = newBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();

    float smoothLoad = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // Do something that takes at least 10ms (on windows)
        try
        {
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 2000000; i++)
                j = (j + i) * j / 2;
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }

        // Calculate coarse CPU usage:
        long time = System.nanoTime();
        long threadTime = newBean.getCurrentThreadCpuTime();
        double load = (threadTime - lastThreadTime) / (double)(time - lastTime);
        // Smooth it.
        smoothLoad += (load - smoothLoad) * 0.1; // damping factor, lower means less responsive, 1 means no smoothing.
        System.out.println(smoothLoad);

        // For next iteration.
        lastTime = time;
        lastThreadTime = threadTime;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible using pure Java. See this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2002-11/01-qa-1108-cpu.html) for some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe if stuck, you might 'sense' cpu availability by running an intermittent bogomips calculator in a background thread, and smoothing and normalising its findings.
...worth a shot no :?

Comment: This is a reasonable idea.  You'll have to use proper microbenchmark tricks though (run for some length of time, warm up all loops before timing, use `System.nanoTime()`). There will still be a fair bit of flutter in performance too over the timing interval.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using linux - just use `jconsole` - you will get all the track of java memory management