# Get CPU Usage using Java API

Tags: java, windows, memory, cpu

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java cpu usage monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062440/java-cpu-usage-monitoring)

I need to know the CPU Usage at an instance of time in terms of % just like the way the Windows Task Manager shows in its performance tab.

please suggest me some way via Java or some native windows command.

rohit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java. The last post looks very promising.