# Inactivity meter

Tags: java, linux, windows, android-activity, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java cpu usage monitoring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062440/java-cpu-usage-monitoring)

I'm trying to write a program in Java that can shutdown your computer when the computer hasn't  been active (like CPU usage) for an amount of time.

I have written a program that can shutdown your pc (windows/mac/linux) after an amount of time. But i don't seem to find a way to check for the CPU usage or inactivity in JAVA.

Can anyone help me pls?

kind regards,

kdlannoy

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6284384/get-memory-and-cpu-usage

Comment: Low CPU usage is not necessarily a sign of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid you probably will have to find a native library. There doesn't appear to be any non-native way of acquiring the CPU usage, however there is support for finding memory usage and other usage indicators.

If you wanted to implement this yourself in a native way, you could look up what terminal command shows you your CPU usage, such as for linux you could execute the `top` command and then parse through Java.

Comment: Thx for the quick response.

I agree with you it is one way of making it possible, but i don't think with the windows built in termal commands this is possible in any way, nor is the stdout retrievable i think.

Comment: @kdlannoy on Windows you can repeatedly run `tasklist.exe /V` which displays the CPU time, retrieve and compare the output over time.

Comment: ty, but i'm looking for a more "beatiful" way to code this.