# How to calculate cpu usage for process java (JavaSysMon)

Tags: java

I use library [JavaSysMon](http://jezhumble.github.io/javasysmon/) to get processes name list but the class `ProcessInfo` has methods `getResidentBytes()`, `getSystemMillis()`.

How to calculate cpu usage for process ?

Comment: What do you mean by "how to calculate"? These two methods return the respective metrics as a number.

Comment: It method getResidentBytes() and  getSystemMillis() isn't involve calculate ?

Comment: did you mean the list of processes `Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -a");`

Comment: Yes  @ Vinayak Pingale
but Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ps -a") work on linux

Comment: I doubt that the two methods calculate anything. They will just pass on the information that the OS has about the process in question.

Comment: Fixed the link and code markup

Comment: Take a look at [java cpu usage monitoring](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2062440/113632), particularly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14712892/113632) which demonstrates how to calculate CPU usage.