# How to get the Window CPU and memory performance using java 1.8?

Tags: java, taskmanager

I want to get the following data using *java 1.8*.

1. CPU Usage.
2. Total Physical Memory
3. Available Memory
4. Free Memory

I have used `OperatingSystemMXBean` but it doesn't have methods to get above data.

Also I used `Runtime.getRuntime()` to get memory size but it return the long value which I unable to convert into *MB* or *GB*.

Comment: you can use `OperatingSystemMXBean` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to monitor the computer's cpu, memory, and disk usage in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java)

Comment: If all else fails, you can investigate Windows API and use [JNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access).

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2062440/java-cpu-usage-monitoring/14712892#14712892 OperatingSystemMXBean can give wrong results or 'not supported' values, and take a look at the source of javasysmon.

Comment: If at all possible, I would recommend trying out the SIGAR API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47177/how-to-monitor-the-computers-cpu-memory-and-disk-usage-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked the javadocs and seems like they are here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html

However; you should be careful with the imported class. You should use the one from the ***com.sun.management*** package, not the one from the ***java.lang.management*** package.

Comment: The link shown display the methods of OperatingSystemMXBe‌​an which is avaliable till java 1.7. Currenty I am using Java 1.8 and it has none of the methods which can dispay the result what I mentioned above.

Comment: As you can see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html they are still included in 1.8

Comment: Thanks. I have changed the package to com.sun.management and got all required methods. `But the getProcessCpuLoad()` and `getSystemCpuLoad()` return -1. How to make this work correctly?

Comment: As far as I have checked the internals of those methods are *as expected* native. So I would go with my own JNI code. http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077361/learn-java/profiling-cpu-usage-from-within-a-java-application.html might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for this useful info. Mentioned code snippet seems a bit complex but I will definitely try to integrate this JNI code.